# List all the Azure instances

Tags: azure

How do I list all the instance computers in my Azure farm? I want to do some internal calls from one instance to all the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should help - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433051.aspx

```
foreach (RoleInstance roleInst in RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Instances)
{
   Trace.WriteLine("Instance ID: " + roleInst.Id);
   foreach (RoleInstanceEndpoint roleInstEndpoint in roleInst.InstanceEndpoints.Values)
   {
      Trace.WriteLine("Instance endpoint IP address and port: " + roleInstEndpoint.IPEndpoint);
   }
}
```

Comment: This only lists the endpoints on the same Azure Cloud Instance and not all the Azure Farms Instances endpoints as requested in the question.

Comment: Apologies - I misunderstood your question, I have answered it in your other question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567435/list-all-instance-endpoints-in-azure-cloud/20629696#20629696